# Greasemonkey Script Version Constant

Tags: version, greasemonkey

I defined the version of my user script in the meta block, like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Script Name
// @description Something about what this script does 
// @include http://www.example.com/
// @version 5.3.0
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==
```

Is there a way to get the version number that I defined? I want to be able to do something like `alert("This is version " + SCRIPT_VERSION + ".");`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you upgrade to Greasemonkey 0.9.16 (just released), you can use the brand new [`GM_info` object](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_info).

You can add this to your script example, above:

```
var myVersion = GM_info.script.version; 

console.log ('Version: ', myVersion, myVersion === "5.3.0");
```

Which would output this to the console:

```
Version: 5.3.0 true
```

---

For GM versions prior to 0.9.16, you'd have to either read your own script in as a `@resource` or use encapsulation techniques as shown in ["Knowing Your Own Metadata"](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Knowing_Your_Own_Metadata).